# portable graphics API

Tags: c++, windows, macos, codeblocks, bgi

I'm learning graphics at school, and the problem is that there we use BGI(C++ with Code::Blocks) and at home I have only mac.

Is there any solution to integrate BGI with Xcode? Or should I use another graphics API?

Actually I only want an API that can be installed on Code::Blocks under windows and on Xcode under mac. So I could take my work home and continue it without - or with minimal code changing.

Comment: The one problem I see with using BGI on Mac is getting a version in Mach-O format. I would strongly recommend against using something different, unless you can convince your teacher that everyone uses something different. Otherwise you'll be the only fool failing class, which would be super annoying. I'd rather use BGI and Code::Blocks in a VirtualBox VM. Note that teachers can be... troublesome with new stuff. Even if you come up with something much better, chances are that you still fail class because you didn't do exactly what the teacher wanted (and he's unable to think outside the box).

Comment: Yes, this is a common problem at teachers.I heard about SDL but I don't know if this is a good solution, and OpenGL is also a possible solution but I'm not very familiar with these.Anyway I'll try VirtualBox, if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

[Antigrain](http://www.antigrain.com/)  is a portable and complete graphics library